# ¿Como puedo detener un SimpleHTTPRequestHandler con CTRL+C desde el CLI de VS Code?

Tags: python, vscode

El siguiente código inicia un servidor, sin embargo, si quiero detenerlo, pulso CTRL + C, pero esto no funciona y continúa funcionando. La única forma es cerrar la terminal. ¿Existe algún modo de que funcione CTRL + C para detener el proceso? Aclaro que esto funciona si nadie ha entrado en el localhost, pero si alguien entra ya no se puede detener. Gracias de antemano.

```
import os
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

curD = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(os.path.join(curD, "static"))

class CORSRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate')
        return super(CORSRequestHandler, self).end_headers()

try:
    httpd = HTTPServer(("localhost", 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)                                                                                                                                   
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    httpd.shutdown()
```

Comment: Asegúrate que en vscode CTRL+C no entre en conflicto con la configuración de teclado para _copiar texto_. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es no usar la terminal desde vscode y arrancar el servidor desde una terminal normal del sistema.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes intentar detenerlo con CTRL+Z si utilizas el PowerShell de Windows o el bash de Linux, eso fuerza la detención del script aunque algunas veces aunque se detenga el código sigue marcando el puerto en uso por un tiempo así que tampoco es la mejor alternativa

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: ¿Qué hace CTRL-Z? ¿Funciona igual en todos los sistemas operativos y en todos los desktop?

Comment: Y si es Linux? Creo que sería con Ctrl+D.

Comment: CTRL+Z funciona para forzar la detención de scrips en python por lo menos en Windows y Linux, en MacOS aunque debería funcionar no lo e probado